# jQuery, array form radio button name problem

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>click div to select hidden options</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.clickDiv {
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 cursor:crosshair;
}
.red {border:1px #000 solid;}
.green {border:1px #000 solid;}
.redBG {background:#F00;}
.greenBG {background:#0F0;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('div.clickDiv.red').click(function(){
  var secilenMadde=$(this).attr('madde');
  $('div#write').text(secilenMadde);
        $('input[name='+secilenMadde+'][value=red]').attr('checked', 'checked');
  $('div.clickDiv.red[madde='+secilenMadde+']').addClass('redBG');
  $('div.clickDiv.green[madde='+secilenMadde+']').removeClass('greenBG');
    });
    $('div.clickDiv.green').click(function(){
  var secilenMadde=$(this).attr('madde');
  $('div#write').text(secilenMadde);
        $('input[name='+secilenMadde+'][value=green]').attr('checked', 'checked');
  $('div.clickDiv.green[madde='+secilenMadde+']').addClass('greenBG');
  $('div.clickDiv.red[madde='+secilenMadde+']').removeClass('redBG');
    });

});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="write"></div>
<form id="formId" name="formName" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="clickDiv red" madde="line1"></div></td>
      <td><div class="clickDiv green" madde="line1"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="clickDiv red" madde="line2"></div></td>
      <td><div class="clickDiv green" madde="line2"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <label for="line1red"><input id="line1red" type="radio" name="line1" value="red" /> Red</label>
  <label for="line1green"><input id="line1green" type="radio" name="line1" value="green" /> Green</label><br />

  <label for="line2red"><input type="radio" name="line2" value="red" /> Red</label>
  <label for="line2green"><input type="radio" name="line2" value="green" /> Green</label>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>click div to select hidden options</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.clickDiv {
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 cursor:crosshair;
}
.red {border:1px #000 solid;}
.green {border:1px #000 solid;}
.redBG {background:#F00;}
.greenBG {background:#0F0;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('div.clickDiv.red').click(function(){
  var secilenMadde=$(this).attr('madde');
  $('div#write').text(secilenMadde);
        $('input[name='+secilenMadde+'][value=red]').attr('checked', 'checked');
  $('div.clickDiv.red[madde='+secilenMadde+']').addClass('redBG');
  $('div.clickDiv.green[madde='+secilenMadde+']').removeClass('greenBG');
    });
    $('div.clickDiv.green').click(function(){
  var secilenMadde=$(this).attr('madde');
  $('div#write').text(secilenMadde);
        $('input[name='+secilenMadde+'][value=green]').attr('checked', 'checked');
  $('div.clickDiv.green[madde='+secilenMadde+']').addClass('greenBG');
  $('div.clickDiv.red[madde='+secilenMadde+']').removeClass('redBG');
    });

});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="write"></div>
<form id="formId" name="formName" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="clickDiv red" madde="line[1]"></div></td>
      <td><div class="clickDiv green" madde="line[1]"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="clickDiv red" madde="line[2]"></div></td>
      <td><div class="clickDiv green" madde="line[2]"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <label for="line1red"><input id="line1red" type="radio" name="line[1]" value="red" /> Red</label>
  <label for="line1green"><input id="line1green" type="radio" name="line[1]" value="green" /> Green</label><br />

  <label for="line2red"><input type="radio" name="line[2]" value="red" /> Red</label>
  <label for="line2green"><input type="radio" name="line[2]" value="green" /> Green</label>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't.

I need input names as an array but it breaks my script. Why?
The propose of the script is selecting radio buttons by clicking divs.

Comment: Could you tell us more about what's breaking? Do you not see any errors anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've put your two examples on JSFiddle.

**Example 1**:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryKjc/1/

**Example 2**:

http://jsfiddle.net/aN6g9/

**Edit**:

Alright, I finally figured out what you're doing here. In the first example, your `secilenMadde` variable is either `line1` or `line2`. In the second one, you're using HTML's form arrays and naming the radio button groups `line[1]` and `line[2]`. The problem is in your selectors. When you make a selection like this in the second example:

```
$('input[name='+secilenMadde+'][value=red]');
```

You're doing this:

```
$('input[name=line[1]][value=red]');
```

Those brackets throw jQuery's selector for a loop, so you must wrap it in double quotes like this:

```
$('input[name="'+secilenMadde+'"][value=red]');
```

Do this for any place you use the `input[name]` selector in conjunction with inner angle brackets and it should work. Proof here:

http://jsfiddle.net/aN6g9/1/

Comment: The propose of the script is selecting radio buttons by clicking divs.

Comment: $('input[name="line[1]"][value=red]');
This is the legal one. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use quotation marks in the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
  attribute
      An attribute name.
  value
      An attribute value. Quotes are mandatory.
```

So, you need to update all of your selectors using `[attribute='value']`.  I've updated your non-working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/PTtFt/

Next time, please narrow down your problem to a more specific piece of code and be more specific about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your names have `[` and `]` in them you need to wrap the name in `"` when used as a selector.

so try with

```
$('input[name="'+secilenMadde+'"][value=green]')
```

Comment: Yes, attribute values without `[]` are usually selected correctly without quotation marks, however, the documentation states that quotation marks are always required for the 'value' portion of the attribute equals selector.

Comment: @Andrew, indeed. Don't think they had the mandatory part in there from the beginning.. Good to know they try enforce it now.